# Monads inside the Kleisli 2-category of another monad

Tags: ct.category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$Let $\cal C$ be a 2-category. Every 2-monad $T$ on $\cal C$ induces a Kleisli 2-category where

- 0-cells are the objects of $\cal C$
- a 1-cell $X\looparrowright Y$ consists of a 1-cell $X\to TY$ in $\cal C$
- a 2-cell $\alpha : f\Rightarrow g$ is a 2-cell between the 1-cells $f,g : X\to TY$.

Composition of 1-cells is defined as in 1-dimensional Kleisli categories:
$$
g\bullet f := \mu_Z\circ Tg\circ f
$$ 
for $f :X\to TY, g  : Y\to TZ$ (and identity of $X$ is the unit $\eta_X$ of the monad).

Vertical composition of 2-cells is obvious to define; horizontal composition takes into account how 1-cells compose, but it's equally rather easy and employs horizontal composition $\boxminus$ of 2-cells in $\cal C$:
$$
\beta \boxminus_\text{Kleisli}\alpha := \mu_Z * (T\beta \boxminus \alpha)
$$ for every pair of 2-cells $\alpha : u \Rightarrow v : A\looparrowright B$ and $ \beta : s\Rightarrow t : B\looparrowright C$.

Now,

> I would like to know what is a monad in this 2-category, and if it is something already known under another name.

Such a monad amounts to

- a 0-cell $A$ in $Kl(T)$;
- an endo-1-cell $s : A\looparrowright A$, i.e. a 1-cell $s : A\to TA$ in $\cal C$
- a pair of 2-cells $\sigma : s\bullet s \Rightarrow s$ and $\nu : \eta_A\Rightarrow s$ such that associativity[1] and unit[2.1, 2.2] axioms hold:
  $$
  \begin{CD}
  \mu_A\cdot Ts\cdot \mu_A\cdot Ts\cdot s @>\mu_A * T\sigma * s>> \mu_A \cdot Ts \cdot s\\
  @V\mu_ATs * \sigma VV [1] @VV\sigma V \\
  \mu_A \cdot Ts\cdot s @>>\sigma > s
  \end{CD}
  \qquad
  \begin{CD}
  \mu_A\cdot T\eta_A\cdot s @>\mu_A * T\nu * s >> \mu_A \cdot Ts\cdot s @<\mu_A Ts * \nu<< \mu_A \cdot Ts\cdot \eta_A\\
  @| [2.1] @V\sigma VV [2.2] @|\\
  s @= s @= s
  \end{CD}
  $$
  I have no idea what such a thing could be.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question as stated, but one situation in which such things come up is if $C$ is a bicategory of spans or profunctors, then monads in $Kl(T)$ are generalized multicategories; see e.g. http://tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/24/21/24-21abs.html